# Dragging acting strange after adding second eventhandler in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

guys! I am having an issue in my JavaFX Application. Images are able to be dragged and placed anywhere on the entire pane. This was working wonderfully, up until I added a second event handler. I added a second event handler to handle deletion. Right-clicking on the image gives you a pop up menu with deletion as an option. As soon as I added this, dragging stopped working properly. While it still works somewhat, the mouse is no longer ever on the image. As soon as you begin dragging, the image jumps over and down like 300 px? I am still able to drag, but I am not dragging on top of the image.

I understand this explanation isn't clear, and I can easily upload a gif of what happens if someone wants me to. Here's the code:

```
@FXML
    private void handleImageButton() 
    {
        System.out.println("Image Clicked");
        closeMenus(6);

        //contains the image path or image URL
        String picURL = imageURL.getText();

        if (!picURL.equals(""))
        {
            Image image = new Image(new File(picURL).toURI().toString());
            ImageView iv = new ImageView();
            iv.setImage(image);
            iv.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
            iv.setOnMousePressed(imageOnMousePressedEventHandler);
            iv.setOnMouseDragged(imageOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);
            workspace.getChildren().add(iv);

            final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem delete = new MenuItem("Delete");
            contextMenu.getItems().addAll(delete);


            iv.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                    if (e.isSecondaryButtonDown()){
                        contextMenu.show(workspace, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
                        delete.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                                workspace.getChildren().remove(iv);
                            }
                        });
                    } //end if
                }
            });

        }
    }

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> imageOnMousePressedEventHandler = 
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                if (ImageTools.isVisible())
                {
                    originalX = t.getSceneX();
                    originalY = t.getSceneY();
                    newX = ((ImageView)(t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
                    newY = ((ImageView)(t.getSource())).getTranslateY();

                    System.out.println("(" + newX + ", " + newY + ")");
                }
            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> imageOnMouseDraggedEventHandler = 
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                if (ImageTools.isVisible())
                {
                    double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - originalX;
                    double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - originalY;
                    double newTranslateX = newX + offsetX;
                    double newTranslateY = newY + offsetY;

                    ((ImageView)(t.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
                    ((ImageView)(t.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);

                    System.out.println("(" + newTranslateX + ", " + newTranslateY + ")");
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding your mouse listeners:

1. iv.setOnMousePressed(imageOnMousePressedEventHandler);
2. iv.setOnMouseDragged(imageOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);
3. iv.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler() {});

setOnXYZ is a setter for a property, holding only one listener, so you are effectively overwriting your listeners in steps 1 and 3.

Use `Node.addEventHandler()` to add multiple handlers for the same EventType or in this case i would suggest using [setOnContextMenuRequested](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnContextMenuRequested-javafx.event.EventHandler-) to show the context menu because it is more convenient and system independent.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I figured I was overriding it.